# Is there a mathematical definition for the "divisibility" of rational numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, rational-numbers

The term *divisibility* usually refers to integer numbers only.

I want to define the divisibility of a rational number $q$ by an integer number $z$ as follows:

$q$ is divisible by $z$ if and only if $m$ is divisible by $z$, where $\frac{m}{n}$ is the simplest form of $q$.

For example: $\frac{91}{10}$ is divisible by $7$.

Is there a mathematical notation or terminology that defines this type of "divisibility"?

---

This issue has occurred to me while reading [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1512443/131263) about the divisibility of $4^n+10\cdot9^{2n-2}$ by $7$.

It is obviously not true for $n=0$, unless we can generalize the definition of *divisibility* for rational numbers as stated above.

Thanks

Comment: The notion is at least a little problematic.  $\frac 25$ is divisible by $2$, $\frac 52$ is divisible by $5$ but $\frac 25 \frac 52=1$ is divisble by neither $2$ nor $5$.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to accomplish.  The usual notion of divisibility applies to the ring (field) of rational numbers, with the result that every number is divisible by every nonzero number.  Perhaps you would be interested in the usual divisibility relation in the context of a ring intermediate between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$?  In particular a ring of quotients, the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the multiplicative set $S$ of integers coprime to $z$.

Comment: @lulu: Thanks (and to the other commentator as well). I now see the problem of generalizing *divisibility* in the way that I have suggested.

Comment: @hardmath: On the micro level, I was really trying to accomplish a way of saying that $7|(4^n+10\cdot9^{2n-2})$ also for $n=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look the notion of discrete valuation, if p is a prime, write $x=p^ia/b$ gcd(a,b)=1, $v_p(x)=i$. Here you can say that $x$ is divisible by p if $v_p(x)>0$, if $x=m/n, gcd(m,n)=1$ write $m=p^ia$, gcd(a,p)=1 $x$ is divisible by p in your sense if and only if $v_p(x)>0$

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be a comment

Comment: @Shailesh It might be short, but this *does* answer the question...

Comment: @A.P. Now OP edited it.  At the time of writing the comment, there was only half a line.

Comment: **Flag** was raised as Not an Answer, OA had originally written only 1/2 a line. So please ignore the flag.

Answer (score 2):

Given a rational number $m/n$
one can go to the localization $R$ (which is a PID) of $\mathbf{Z}$ at a suitable prime $p$ not a factor of $n$, and so $m/n$ will  be an element of $R$. Being a PID one can define divisibility there.